# Can't install yasnippet?

Tags: emacs, code-snippets

I tried to install yasnippet using the "normal install" protocol given [here](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/).  After placing the yasnippet-0.6.1c folder in ~/.emacs.d/plugins/, I tried to eval the following in my .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path
              "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet-0.6.1c")
(require 'yasnippet) ;; not yasnippet-bundle
(yas/initialize)
(yas/load-directory "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet-0.6.1c/snippets")
```

At the second sexp, I get the backtrace:

```
 Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable yasnippet-bundle)
 eval(yasnippet-bundle)
 eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
 eval-last-sexp(nil)
 call-interactively(eval-last-sexp)
 recursive-edit()
 byte-code(...
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction with this?  I'm not familiar enough with Emacs to be certain that this is not a user error, but it would seem from the backtrace that at least the loadpath was correct.

This is yasnippet 0.6.1c.  I can reproduce it on Aquamacs 1.9 and GNU Emacs 22.2.1 under OSX 10.4 and GNU Emacs 23 under Ubuntu 10.04.  Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(add-to-list 'load-path
              "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet-0.6.1c")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response.  Tried this out of curiousity, but it didn't work.  (Got an identical backtrace as above.)  If you don't mind explaining in further detail:


The directory really is "[...]-0.6.1c".  Why would I append an "l"?

The backtrace seems to suggest to me that Emacs successfully found yasnippet.el in said directory.  Is that not the case?

Why would appending an "l" to the path _ever_ be a solution to a problem like this?  :-)


Thanks again.

Comment: @wvoq that was typo on my part (sorry).  You specified yasnippet file rather than directory as your load path.

Comment: @aaa sorry, I mis-copied the path.  When I try: (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet-0.6.1c") I still get the same backtrace about yasnippet-bundle being void, though.

Comment: @wvoq do you have `(require 'yasnippet-bundle)` anywhere?

Comment: @aaa I don't, at least not in my .emacs.  It's my (shaky) understanding that yasnippet-bundle compiles all the defined snippets, and is supposed to be created by yasnippet.el(?).  

I guess I'll just eval yasnippet.el sexp by sexp until it breaks down, and see if that tells me anything.  Thanks for all your attention on this.

Comment: @my only other guess is you have function `yas/compile-* bundle` call somewhere.  on Ubuntu  you can try to install http://ftp.debian.org/pool/main/y/yasnippet

Comment: @aaa well synaptic fixed it automagically for me.  I still don't understand why the out-of-the-box installation would appear broken on two different architectures, but at least it's running now.  Thanks again, I'm much obliged.

Comment: @wvoq you may want to send a bug report to developers.
I looked at source files, but did not see anything (I am not very good however)

Comment: @aaa I sent a bug report to the yasnippet folks, and it got classified as irreproducible.  The weirdest thing about this issue was that when I traced (require 'yasnippet) with edebug it actually evaluated.  I'll try installing on another machine at school and see if I can reproduce it afresh.  Thanks again!